# namespace problem, multiple projects in single solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, namespaces

I am following example from MVC book. I was asked to create three projects in one solution ( C# Library, MVC 2 and Test). I did it by right clicking on solution name and choose 'add > new project'. Project names are:

```
MVCSample.Domain
MVCSample.WebUI
MVCSample.Test
```

It looks fine but I can not add `Domain` namespace into class from `WebUI` project. When I am writing `using MVCSample.` statement in controler ( class form `WebUI`) InteliSense prompt only `.WebUI` as matching ending. What did I wrong?

I am using VS 2010 pro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't added a reference to the Domain project from the WebUI project.

Right-click on the WebUI project in Solution Explorer, pick Add Reference and then choose the Domain project.

Comment: Thanks, perfect solution... and written in a book too. I don't know how I missed it ;(